# Unable to set the text and its pin in correct orientation in Tikz pie chart

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am modifying the pie chart, which is available [here](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/pie-chart-color/). In case of small slices, text inside the pie chart overlaps to each other. So I am trying to write the text and value outside the chart. Below is my modified latex code-

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows}

\makeatletter
\def\tikz@auto@anchor{%
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro\angle{atan2(\pgf@x,\pgf@y)-90}
    \edef\tikz@anchor{\angle}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
    \def\angle{0}
    \def\radius{2}
    \def\cyclelist{{"orange","blue","gray","red","green","cyan","magenta"}}

    \centering
    \newcount\cyclecount \cyclecount=-1
    \newcount\ind \ind=-1
    \begin{tikzpicture}[nodes = {font=\small}]
      \foreach \percent/\name in {
        2/3,
        2/4,
        2/5,
        18/7,
        13/8,
        63/9,
        } {
          \ifx\percent\empty\else               % If \percent is empty, do nothing
            \global\advance\cyclecount by 1     % Advance cyclecount
            \global\advance\ind by 1            % Advance list index
            \ifnum6<\cyclecount                 % If cyclecount is larger than list
              \global\cyclecount=0              %   reset cyclecount and
              \global\ind=0                     %   reset list index
            \fi
            \pgfmathparse{\cyclelist[\the\ind]} % Get color from cycle list
            \edef\color{\pgfmathresult}         %   and store as \color
            \draw[fill={\color!50},draw={\color}] (0,0) -- (\angle:\radius)
              arc (\angle:\angle+\percent*3.6:\radius) -- cycle;
            \node[pin={[pin distance=1cm]\angle+0.5*\percent*3.6:{\name~[\percent\%]}}]
              at (\angle+0.5*\percent*3.6:\radius) {};
            \pgfmathparse{\angle+\percent*3.6}  % Advance angle
            \xdef\angle{\pgfmathresult}         %   and store in \angle
          \fi
        };
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

I have followed some answers given for [How can I force TikZ pin angle?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/43955/49520) and [pgfplot pin length](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/69685/49520) but they are not working well. Below is the screenshot of generated pdf-

[image]

I have following questions-

1. How to orient the pin properly i.e. direction towards the center of circle
2. The angle at which text and pin are oriented, must be half of the angle of that slice

Comment: The syntax for the `atan2` function changed recently: the arguments are now swapped. Try using `atan2(\pgf@y,\pgf@x)` instead of `atan2(\pgf@x,\pgf@y)`.

Comment: @Jake : You are absolutely right. Thanks a ton. You may answer the question, if you have more info to share :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would avoid using the `pin` option (you have to compute positions anyway!)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
    \def\angle{0}
    \def\radius{2}
    \def\labelradius{3}
    \def\cyclelist{{"orange","blue","gray","red","green","cyan","magenta"}}

    \centering
    \newcount\cyclecount \cyclecount=-1
    \newcount\ind \ind=-1
    \begin{tikzpicture}[nodes = {font=\small}]
      \foreach \percent/\name in {
        2/3,
        2/4,
        2/5,
        18/7,
        13/8,
        63/9,
        } {
          \ifx\percent\empty\else               % If \percent is empty, do nothing
            \global\advance\cyclecount by 1     % Advance cyclecount
            \global\advance\ind by 1            % Advance list index
            \ifnum6<\cyclecount                 % If cyclecount is larger than list
              \global\cyclecount=0              %   reset cyclecount and
              \global\ind=0                     %   reset list index
            \fi
            \pgfmathparse{\cyclelist[\the\ind]} % Get color from cycle list
            \edef\color{\pgfmathresult}         %   and store as \color
            \draw[fill={\color!50},draw={\color}] (0,0) -- (\angle:\radius)
              arc (\angle:\angle+\percent*3.6:\radius) -- cycle;
            % \node[pin={[pin distance=1cm]\angle+0.5*\percent*3.6:{\name~[\percent\%]}}]
            %   at (\angle+0.5*\percent*3.6:\radius) {};
            \draw[draw=gray, shorten >=2pt] (\angle+0.5*\percent*3.6:\labelradius) node {\name~[\percent\%]} edge (\angle+0.5*\percent*3.6:\radius);
            \pgfmathparse{\angle+\percent*3.6}  % Advance angle
            \xdef\angle{\pgfmathresult}         %   and store in \angle
          \fi
        };
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image: preview]

Answer (score 2):

A PSTricks solution:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}

\def\slice[#1](#2)#3#4{
  \rput(psChartI#2){\SI{#3}{\tonne}}
  \ncline{psChartO#2}{psChart#2}
  \nput{#1}{psChartO#2}{#4}
}
% Use of the \slice macro:
% \slice%
% [position of outer node, relative to the line end-point]
% (slice number)
% {size of the slice, relative to the whole pie}
% {outer node}


\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\def\before{54}
\def\under{594}
\def\after{890}
\centering
 \psset{
   unit = 2.8,
   nodesepB = -5pt
 }
  \begin{pspicture}(-1,-1.37)(1.5,1.4)
    \psChart[
      userColor = {red!70, green!70, blue!70},
      chartNodeO = 1.2,
      shadow = true,
      shadowsize = 5pt,
      linewidth = 0
    ]{\before, \under, \after}{}{}
    \slice[0](1){\before}{Before}
    \slice[90](2){\under}{Under}
    \slice[270](3){\after}{After}
  \end{pspicture}
 \caption{Distribution of something.}
 \label{fig:piechart}
\end{figure}
This is figure~\ref{fig:piechart}.

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

For more on the `\psChart` macro, see [page 16 in the `pstricks-add` manual](http://mirrors.dotsrc.org/ctan/graphics/pstricks/contrib/pstricks-add/doc/pstricks-add-doc.pdf#page=16).

Comment: I would love it more if it belongs to `tikz`. By the way thanks a lot.

Comment: @RaviJoshi I don't know TikZ, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to check [this recent question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/394412/how-to-adjust-pie-chart-labels-horizontally-and-add-pins-to-labels-of-small-perc/394543#394543). The shape of the pin can be modified but the basic idea is there